# Applescript set selection to filename

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I'm building a service to create a new file in finder.  The first step runs the following bash script

```
for f in "$@"
do
    touch ${f}/untitled.txt
done
```

This creates a file called untitled.txt What I would like to have happen next is to have that file selected and if possible have it be selected to rename, exactly as if I selected the file and pressed rename. Just like it would happen on a windows machine. Then end result would ideally be my finder window looks like this

[image]

I've tried

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selection to "untitled.txt"
end tell
```

But that produced an error. I am sure this is possible using applescript, but I can't find a good example for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
tell application "Finder"
    reveal (path to desktop folder as string) & "untitled.txt"
    activate
    delay 0.5
end tell
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
```

Of course you'll have to get the right path to your **untitled.txt**. 
The Finder shows the file in a Finder window and selects it. After a minimum delay we simulate a pressed *return*-Key.

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg